# How to fix opencart default timezone

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, timezone, opencart2.x

my opencart version is 2.3.02
all my activities' time-stamp is showing 1 hour advanced.

hosting server timezone 'America/Chicago'
I'm trying to set it to 'Europe/London'

I've tried php.ini, .htaccess and changing scripts here & there but found no solution. 
Could somebody please tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The following instruction in the Opencart forum solved the issue for me:
https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=31844&p=260898&hilit=timezone

I have updated system/startup.php

```
// if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
//  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
// }
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone with querying;

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/London';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: In the file "my.cnf" in the [mysqld] section

Comment: I'm with a shared hosting right now.  cannot find the file in cPanel file-manager :(

Comment: It would be a good approach to research about the problem.

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/is-there-a-way-to-find-my-cnf-in-shared-hosting

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please though include some explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem. This may help - [answer]

Comment: I already have set date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
but still no solution, I think there is something wrong with mysql timezone setup ...